# Cannot access second form element with javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

The problem is, userid is grabbed just fine, but the second element "passwordfield" and all the remaining element ALWAYS returns null. I've tried all methods for grabbing this element value but they always return a null object, and then my code throws and error when I try and access the value of a null.

Here is my script.

```
function formValidation() {
    var uid = document.registration.userid.value;
    document.write("<h1>" + uid + "</h1>");
    try {
        var passid = document.registration.passwordfield.value;
        document.write("<h1>" + passid.value + "</h1>");
    } catch (error) {
        alert(error);
    }
    var uname = document.getElementById("username");
    document.write("<h1>" + uname + "</h1>");
    var uadd = document.getElementById("address");
    document.write("<h1>" + uadd + "</h1>");
    var ucountry = document.getElementById("country");
    document.write("<h1>" + uncountry + "</h1>");
    var uzip = document.getElementById("zip");
    document.write("<h1>" + uzip + "</h1>");
    var uemail = document.getElementById("email");
    document.write("<h1>" + uemail + "</h1>"); 

    {
        if (passid_validation(passid, 7, 12)) {
            if (allLetter(uname)) {
                if (alphanumeric(uadd)) {
                    if (countryselect(ucountry)) {
                        if (allnumeric(uzip)) {
                            if (ValidateEmail(uemail)) {
                                if (validsex(umsex, ufsex)) {}
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function userid_validation(uid, mx, my) {
    var uid_len = uid.value.length;
    if (uid_len == 0 || uid_len >= my || uid_len < mx) {
        alert("User Id should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
        uid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function passid_validation(passid, mx, my) {
    var passid_len = passid.value.length;
    if (passid_len == 0 || passid_len >= my || passid_len < mx) {
        alert("Password should not be empty / length be between " + mx + " to " + my);
        passid.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

function allLetter(uname) {
    var letters = /^[A-Za-z]+$/;
    if (uname.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('Username must have alphabet characters only');
        uname.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function alphanumeric(uadd) {
    var letters = /^[0-9a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if (uadd.value.match(letters)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('User address must have alphanumeric characters only');
        uadd.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function countryselect(ucountry) {
    if (ucountry.value == "Default") {
        alert('Select your country from the list');
        ucountry.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

function allnumeric(uzip) {
    var numbers = /^[0-9]+$/;
    if (uzip.value.match(numbers)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert('ZIP code must have numeric characters only');
        uzip.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function ValidateEmail(uemail) {
    var mailformat = /^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$/;
    if (uemail.value.match(mailformat)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        alert("You have entered an invalid email address!");
        uemail.focus();
        return false;
    }
}

function validsex(umsex, ufsex) {
    x = 0;
    if (umsex.checked) {
        x++;
    }
    if (ufsex.checked) {
        x++;
    }
    if (x == 0) {
        alert('Select Male/Female');
        umsex.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        alert('Form Successfully Submitted');
        window.location.reload()
        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is my html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<title>form</title>

<script src="hai.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Registration Form</h1>
<p>Use tab keys to move from one input field to the next.</p>
<form name="registration" onSubmit="return formValidation();" action="hai.js"  METHOD="POST">
    User id:
    <input type="text" name="userid" size="12" /><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="passwordfield" size="12" /><br>
    Name:
    <input type="text" name="username" size="50" /><br>
    Address:
    <input type="text" name="address" size="50" /><br>
    Country:
    <select name="country">
    <option selected="" value="Default">(Please select a country)</option>
    <option value="AF">Australia</option>
    <option value="AL">Canada</option>
    <option value="DZ">India</option>
    <option value="AS">Russia</option>
    <option value="AD">USA</option>
    </select><br>
    ZIP
    <input type="text" name="zip" /><br>
    Email:
    <input type="text" name="email" size="50" /><br>
    Sex:
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Male" /><span>Male</span><br>
    <input type="radio" name="sex" value="Female" /><span>Female</span><br>
    Language
    <input type="checkbox" name="en" value="en" checked /><span>English</span><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="nonen" value="noen" /><span>Non English</span><br>
    About:<br>
    <textarea name="desc" id="desc"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using `document.write` after the page has loaded. It destroys the existing content.

Comment: ...and give serious consideration to neatly indenting your code.

Comment: You should probably also give `id`s to your elements when you want to use `getElementById`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might be with document.write, as if it runs after the page has loaded it will overwrite your page, and then of course you can't access the elements anymore.

Also, why do you use document.registration.userid but not document.registration.username? Depending on your browser getElementById might not work on name attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the document.write() before the password field.. for some reason calling it removes the registration variable form the document... 
i am not quite sure why ...

but i tried removing it "the document.write" and adding the nodes the recommended way:

```
var myElement = document.createElement("h1");
myElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("My Text here"));
document.appendChild(myElement);
```

it worked just fine... 
you should read this: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/
i think it might help you a little bit :)